# Permission denied accessing HDFS via Hadoop java API

Tags: java, hadoop, permissions, hdfs

As part of a jar ran through hadoop, I want to implement a simple function that (a) creates a file if it doesn't exist, (b) appends bytes from a string passed in on a new line into this file.

I wrote the following:

```
public class FSFacade {
  private static FileContext fc = FileCOntext.getFileContext();

  public static void appendRawText(Path p, String data) throws IOException {
    InputStream is
        = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    FsPermission permissions
        = new FsPermission(FsAction.ALL, FsAction.ALL, FsAction.ALL);
    OutputStream os
        = fc.create(p,
                    EnumSet.of(CREATE, APPEND),
                    CreateOpts.perms(permissions),
                    CreateOpts.createParents());

    IOUtils.copyBytes(is, os, new Configuration());
  }
}
```

This code works fine in Eclipse, but when I try and run it on an HDFS via `hadoop jar` it raises either of the following exceptions:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /out (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /results/out (no such file or directory)
```

I assume the first one is raised because my process doesn't have permissions to write to the root of the HDFS.  The second one probably means my code somehow doesn't create the file if it doesn't exist yet.

How can I make sure, programatically, that my process
(a) has all the appropriate permissions to write into the `Path` passed in ? (I presume it means execute perms on all folders in the path and write perms on the last one ?)
(b) indeed creates the file if it doesn't exist yet, as I expected `EnumSet.of(CREATE, APPEND)` to do ?

Comment: Can you show the permissions of root path? Which user did you use? And for the second, you will want to call mkdirs for intermediate directories to any file

Comment: I can see permissions of `/` contents with `bin/hdfs dfs -ls /` but I'm not sure how to view permissions on `/` itself?  I am also not sure which user I use, I just call `bin/hadoop jar my-program.jar param1 param2 ...`.    I am aware of mkdirs, although I expected that `CreateOpts.createParents()` would do it?

Comment: If you don't have Kerberos enabled, the user permissions being checked are by whatever user you run the command as. If you run `whoami`, that'll tell you.

Comment: I typically use the Filesystem class. I'm personally not aware of how FileContext works

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to give permission to write into HDFS

```
> hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /*
```

`*` means permissions will be enabled for all folders 
`777` will enable all permissions (read , write and execute)

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks adarsh. It may, but does not answer my question. I deploy to a fresh AWS EMR cluster each time I run the jar so setting permissions manually is far from ideal, if it works at all.  Ultimately I need to solve this programmatically.